# finding cache L1 and L2 bandwidth

Tags: caching, hardware, bandwidth

I'm trying to find the bandwidth of my computer's L1 and L2 cache. How can I determine either the theoretical value or the effective value trough benchmarks or so?

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be useful. It gives outputs of cache reads/writes and probably has detailed data if you learn how to use it.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.running-cachegrind

This may be helpful as well. I'm running it and it's spitting out some values I'm not quite sure how to interpret. Doesn't seem to break down L1 vs. L2 but maybe in accordance with valgrind you could figure something out?

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/llcbench/cachebench.html

Answer (score 1):

This is non-free software. But if what you are looking for is a program to tell you the output for *your* computer you should give [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/) (on windows) a try.

If you are looking to determine this vie a program you are writing the answer is highly system dependent. On linux the information is in the `/proc/` hierarchy. As for windows I cannot tell you the answer.